# Problem typing @ character at command prompt under HP-UX

Tags: hp-ux, stty, text-user-interface

Under HP-UX Model :9000/800 O/S = B.11.11

Problem to type @ character on command prompt as well as in vi editor also.

When I try to type "@" this character I won't get anything.
line for export command i need to use @.

Comment: that's not the model name, but this is irrevelent, I seems to recall that @ is use to cancel the line. see `stty`. I don't have an HP-UX available yet, so I can't give more clues.

Comment: As Archemar pointed out, apparently @ is used as 'kill' character. This could help solve your problem - http://softpanorama.org/Commercial_unixes/HPUX/index.shtml .

Comment: Also, this has been modified in the more recent releases, I have 11.23 and these are the stty settings `intr = ^C; erase = DEL; kill = ^U;`

Answer (score 2):

Comments to the contrary, if you do an `stty sane` on HPUX,

- the `kill` character is (re)set to `@`.
- `erase` is set to `#`
- `intr` is set to ASCII DEL (often shown as `^?`)

That was from testing HPUX 11.11, 11.23 and 11.31 (other systems such as AIX and Solaris also have quirks like this).

Further reading:

- [stty defaults on various unix flavours](http://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/stty/)
- [After using @, line breaks for a particular user in shell HP-UX](http://www.unix.com/hp-ux/256104-after-using-line-breaks-particular-user-shell.html)

Answer (score 0):

For the impatient people, run the below command,

```
stty kill '^U'
```

This will assign `Ctrl-U` sequence for line kill (instead of `@`) and you can now type `@` character in the shell. You can also put the same command in your shell startup file (e.g. `.bash_profile`).